# Implementing faster python inner product with BLAS

Tags: python, numpy, cython, linear-algebra, blas

I found [this useful tutorial](https://iamtrask.github.io/2014/11/23/cython-blas-fortran/) on using low-level BLAS functions (implemented in Cython) to get big speed improvements over standard numpy linear algebra routines in python. Now, I've successfully gotten the *vector* product working fine. First I save the following as `linalg.pyx`:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libc.math cimport exp
from libc.string cimport memset

from scipy.linalg.blas import fblas

REAL = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t REAL_t

cdef extern from "/home/jlorince/flda/voidptr.h":
    void* PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(object obj)

ctypedef double (*ddot_ptr) (const int *N, const double *X, const int *incX, const double *Y, const int *incY) nogil
cdef ddot_ptr ddot=<ddot_ptr>PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(fblas.ddot._cpointer)  # vector-vector multiplication 

cdef int ONE = 1
def vec_vec(syn0, syn1, size):
    cdef int lSize = size
    f = <REAL_t>ddot(&lSize, <REAL_t *>(np.PyArray_DATA(syn0)), &ONE, <REAL_t *>(np.PyArray_DATA(syn1)), &ONE)
    return f
```

(source code for voidptr.h available [here](https://github.com/klb3713/sentence2vec/blob/master/voidptr.h))

Once I compile it, it works fine, and is definitely faster than `np.inner`:

```
In [1]: import linalg
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = np.random.random(100)
In [4]: %timeit np.inner(x,x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 µs per loop
In [5]: %timeit linalg.vec_vec(x,x,100)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 483 ns per loop
In [8]: np.all(np.inner(x,x)==linalg.vec_vec(x,x,100))
Out[8]: True
```

Now, this is great, but only works for the case of calculating the dot/inner product (equivalent in this case) of two *vectors*. What I need to do now, implement similar functions (that I hope will offer similar speedups) for doing vector-matrix *inner* products. That is, I want to replicate the functionality of `np.inner` when passed a 1D array and a 2D matrix:

```
In [4]: x = np.random.random(5)
In [5]: y = np.random.random((5,5))
In [6]: np.inner(x,y)
Out[6]: array([ 1.42116225,  1.13242989,  1.95690196,  1.87691992,  0.93967486])
```

This is equivalent to calculating the inner/dot products (again, equivalent for 1D arrays) of the 1D array and each row of the matrix:

```
In [32]: [np.inner(x,row) for row in y]
Out[32]:
[1.4211622497461549, 1.1324298918119025, 1.9569019618096966,1.8769199192990056, 0.93967485730285505]
```

From what I've seen of the BLAS documentation, I think I need to start with something like this (using dgemv):

```
ctypedef double (*dgemv_ptr) (const str *TRANS, const int *M, const int *N, const double *ALPHA, const double *A, const int *LDA, const double *X, const int *incX, const double *BETA, const double *Y, const int *incY)
cdef dgemv_ptr dgemv=<dgemv>PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(fblas.dgemv._cpointer)  # matrix vector multiplication
```

But I need help (a) defining the actual function that I can use in Python (i.e. a `vec-matrix` function analogous to `vec_vec` above), and (b) knowing how to use it to properly replicate the behavior of `np.inner`, which is what I need for the model I'm implementing.

**Edit:** [Here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/da8/dgemv_8f.html) is the link to relevant BLAS documentation for dgemv, that I need to be using, which is confirmed here:

```
In [13]: np.allclose(scipy.linalg.blas.fblas.dgemv(1.0,y,x), np.inner(x,y))
Out[13]: True
```

But using it out of the box like this is actually slower than pure np.inner, so I still need help with the Cython implementation.

**Edit2** Here's my latest attempt at this, which compiles fine but crashes python with a segmentation fault whenever I try to run it:

```
cdef int ONE = 1
cdef char tr = 'n'
cdef REAL_t ZEROF = <REAL_t>0.0
cdef REAL_t ONEF = <REAL_t>1.0
def mat_vec(mat,vec,mat_rows,mat_cols):
    cdef int m = mat_rows
    cdef int n = mat_cols
    out = <REAL_t>dgemv(&tr, &m, &n, &ONEF, <REAL_t *>(np.PyArray_DATA(mat)), &m, <REAL_t *>(np.PyArray_DATA(vec)), &ONE, &ZEROF, NULL, &ONE)
    return out
```

After compiling, I try to run `linalg.mat_vec(y,x,5,5)`, (using the same x and y as above) but this just crashes. I think I'm close, but don't know what else to change...

Comment: Why aren't you just using ``np.dot``?

Comment: For the first case (what I already have implemented), dot and inner product are equivalent mathematically for two 1D vectors, but inner is slightly faster. For the second case I describe, the model I'm building requires computations that require me to do exactly what `np.inner` does for a 1D array and a 2D matrix (i.e. the dot/inner product of the array and each row of the matrix), which is much faster than iterating over the matrix and calculating each inner/dot product separately.

Comment: And in any case, this is all part of big complicated monte carlo model where I need to do all these computations many, many times, so I'm trying to squeeze every bit of speed out of this that I can.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... but In your example with the `x` and `y` vectors above, `np.allclose(np.inner(x,y), y.dot(x))`?

Comment: @BeRecursive Yep! Also the same as `np.dot(y,x)` (but not `np.dot(x,y)`). Clearly I'm a bit rusty on my linear algebra, but I guess this does mean my implementation could just be a standard matrix-vector dot product.

Comment: Yes, well ``np.dot`` and ``array.dot`` are the same method. The second is just placed on the ndarray object for convenience. Makes the code look more like matrix multiplications. What I was trying to say is, why bother writing your own Cython when you can just the numpy blas methods? Which I can assure you are well optimised? Don't use ``np.inner``, it isn't optimised. Always use ``np.dot``.

Comment: Because the Cython approach is demonstrably faster, because it prevents copying of data behind the scenes. You can see in the second code block above that the cython approach is ~3x faster! You may be right that np.dot can outperform np.inner in some cases, but I've done lots of speed tests showing the opposite (seems to depend on the array size)

Comment: But I would again point to the tutorial at https://iamtrask.github.io/2014/11/23/cython-blas-fortran/ describing why the Cython implementation is faster. Now, I suppose it's possible this is some oddity that only holds for vector-vector products, as opposed to matrix-vector products, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Here are more extensive speed tests backing up everything I've said here: https://gist.github.com/moustachio/7bc087eab98070950fe8 (long story short, inner seems to outperform dot reliably, and the cython approach outperforms both, and more so for smaller vectors)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86783/discussion-between-berecursive-and-moustachio).

Comment: What you could do is to switch to a version of Numpy/Scipy optimized with Intel's MKL.

Comment: Maybe I'm being too naive, but afaik `dgemv` wants a `y` matrix to be non-NULL where to store the result, and you're passing NULL?

Answer (score 2):

Per @Pietro Saccardi:

```
int dgemv_(char *trans, integer *m, integer *n, doublereal *
           alpha, doublereal *a, integer *lda, doublereal *x, integer *incx, 
           doublereal *beta, doublereal *y, integer *incy)

...

Y      - DOUBLE PRECISION array of DIMENSION at least   
         ( 1 + ( m - 1 )*abs( INCY ) ) when TRANS = 'N' or 'n'   
         and at least   
         ( 1 + ( n - 1 )*abs( INCY ) ) otherwise.   
         Before entry with BETA non-zero, the incremented array Y   
         must contain the vector y. On exit, Y is overwritten by the
         updated vector y.
```

I doubt you can use `NULL` for `Y` in the call.

Comment: The doc also states:  `BETA is DOUBLE PRECISION. On entry, BETA specifies the scalar beta. When BETA is supplied as zero then Y need not be set on input.`, and in the op case, BETA is specified.